# fglrx driver missing after update 12.04

Tags: drivers, ati, fglrx

I updated my latop recently and after the update it started overheating and shutting down.

This is problem which I have had previously on this laptop and the solution was to use fglrx driver. The opensource driver overheats my laptop which has a good change of damaging my hardware.

So knowing this I checked additional drivers and discovered that fglrx was no longer an option.

What has happened to fglrx and how do I get it back?

My graphics card is a Mobility Radeon HD 4530.

As previously stated the opensource driver is not an option because it causes my laptop to overheat and shutdown.

To clarify, I want to know why the driver was removed in the update and get back to the official distro version of fglrx not install the latest from ati.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Found this report on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fglrx-installer/+bug/1276379